# Asp.Net Core docker application write log to stdout

Tags: docker, logging, asp.net-core, stdout

How can force my Asp.Net Core Docker application write logs to stdout?

Comment: `docker-compose up` without detached mode will produce logs in stdout

Comment: @t-prisar OK, what logging provider i need use in this case? Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console?

Comment: `ILoggerFactory` from `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` will help to put logging to your console.